# haskell function declaration

Tags: haskell

I have been playing around with haskell and I found out that if I write the following function in a code file:

```
f :: Int -> [a] -> a
f idx str = last $ (take . succ) idx str
```

then this works totally fine.  Naturally, I figured the code would look better without the arguments.

```
f :: Int -> [a] -> a
f = last $ (take . succ)
```

But this generates an error when I try to load it into gchi

```
Couldn't match expected type `[a]'
       against inferred type `Int -> [a1] -> [a1]'
In the second argument of `($)', namely `(take . succ)'
In the expression: last $ (take . succ)
In the definition of `f': f = last $ (take . succ)
```

Failed, modules loaded: none.

I'm kind of confused about how this could be happening...

Comment: +1 for forcing me to overcome my complete lack of focus and think about Haskell, which I haven't looked at in months. Hope I can focus some more and refine my answer into something more useful.

Comment: As a **rule of thumb**: If you want to get rid of a (on both sides) trailing argument, replace all top level `$` by `.` (this works only in "simple" cases)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what happens when you try to compose `last` with `(take . succ)`

```
:t (.)
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c

last :: [t] -> t  ~ (b -> c)  
-- so b ~ [t] and c ~ t   

(take . succ) :: Int -> [t] -> [t]  
-- so a ~ int and b ~ [t] -> [t]
```

Type of b is inferred to be `[t]` from `last` but it couldn't match against the type of b in `(take . succ)` which is `[t] -> [t]`

Answer (score 10):

You're misunderstanding the precedence. This:

```
f idx str = last $ (take . succ) idx str
```

Is parsed like this:

```
f idx str = last $ ( (take . succ) idx str )
```

Not (as you think) like this:

```
f idx str = ( last $ (take . succ) ) idx str
```

`$` has extremely the lowest precedence of any operator, and function calling has extremely the highest. `.` has the second highest, so `(take . succ)` binds to it's arguments (`idx str`) before it binds to `last $`.

Furthermore, the function (as it compiles) doesn't do what it looks like you want it to do. It increments `idx`, then takes that character from the string. If that's what you want, why use `succ` when `(+1)` works? You've already restricted the type to integers.

As written, your function is identical to the `!!` operator - it's just an array index function. Is this what you want? Or do you want to `succ` the item at the given index? You could accomplish that with the following:

```
f :: Enum a => Int -> [a] -> a
f idx str = succ $ str !! idx
-- or
f idx str = succ $ (!!) str idx
-- or, only one argument
f idx = succ . (!! idx)
```

I'm still working on a version with no written arguments. Perhaps it's more important to write working code? ;)

Comment: Yes, all that is correct.  Unless you consider "with type" `::` to be an operator, which has lower precedence than `($)`.

Comment: @luqui - Yeah, I was verifying this myself. Good to know about `::` though. It would make sense for it to be the lowest precedence. Is it considered an operator?

Comment: @Chris, technically no; it has a special place in the grammar.

Comment: I was actually trying duplicate the (!!) operator without using written arguments.  I am a haskell newb and I figured it might be an interesting exercise.  This version fails to throw exceptions if you try something like f 20 [1..10] though, so it's definitely incorrect as written.

Comment: @chuck taylor - Ah. I was wondering why you'd try to duplicate it. I'd use pattern matching personally. And I don't think it's very nice to say it's "definitely incorrect as written" since you didn't specify any requirements. If you're trying to reimplement built-in behavior, you should say so off the bat. Otherwise you'll get a lot of answers (like mine) telling you not to do that.

Comment: @chris lutz- I meant that the function that I defined in the question is definitely incorrect as an implementation of (!!), which is my own fault.  I didn't bring up that it was originally an attempt at (!!) since I noticed that it wasn't actually right separately from the precedence issue and I didn't want to distract from that.

Answer (score 5):

```
f idx str = last $ (take . succ) idx str
-- applying definition of ($)
f idx str = last ((take . succ) idx str)
-- adding parentheses for clarity
f idx str = last (((take . succ) idx) str)
-- using definition of (.)
f idx str = (last . (take . succ) idx) str
-- η-conversion
f idx = last . (take . succ) idx
-- infix to prefix notation
f idx = (.) last ((take . succ) idx)
-- ading parentheses for clarity
f idx = ((.) last) ((take . succ) idx)
-- using definition of (.)
f idx = ((.) last . (take . succ)) idx
-- η-conversion
f = (.) last . (take . succ)
-- remove parentheses: (.) is right-associative
f = (.) last . take . succ
```

Comment: I don't think you have enough `.`s there.